# Do you know this colorpicker?

Tags: jquery, plugin

I'm searching for a good looking colorpicker. I just found a screenshot: 
[image]

Do you know which plugin is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some that might be it or look very similar:

- http://automattic.github.io/Iris/ --  I think it is this one, it doesn't have the "Current Color" or "Default", but I think those are what the user would click on to bring up the color picker.
- http://bebraw.github.io/colorjoe/
- http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/